# Bash - Search and Replace operation with reporting the files and lines that has changed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an input file "test.txt" as below -

```
host = abc.com host = xyz.com
db-host = abc.com db-host = xyz.com
```

In each line, the value before space is the old value which needs to be replaced by the new value after space recursively in a folder named "test"

"sed" replaces the strings on the fly in 100s of files.

Is there a trick or an alternative way by which I can get a report of the files changed like the absolute path of the file & the exact lines that got changed?

PS - I understand that sed or stream editors don't support this functionality out of the box. I don't want to use versioning as it will be an overkill for this task.

Comment: Using something like git I don't think is overkill at all. It is quick and easy to set up and has a small "foot print". Just run "git init" and you are away. It's exactly what you need as well.

Comment: I need to use the shell script for this task. I am only stuck in **search & replace** function.

Comment: you need data i.e. key=latest_value in same file or in different file?

Comment: I took that question as reference because that question was looking like my requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with `perl`:

```
find -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec perl -i -lape 'if (/.+\s=\s.+\s.+\s=\s.+/) {s/.+\s=\s.+\s(.+\s=\s.+)/\1/; push (@lines, $_);} END {if (@lines) {print STDOUT "\n" . $ARGV . ":"; foreach (@lines){print "$_";}}}' {} \;
```

Breakdown:

`find -type f -iname '*.txt'` look for files in the current directory and subdirectories, whose filename ends in `.txt`

`-exec` run the following command on each file that gets found

`perl -i -lape` in place edit files according to the following `perl` script.

`if (/.+\s=\s.+\s.+\s=\s.+/)` if the line matches the pattern you gave: `xxx = xxx xxx = xxx` where `x` is any character

`{s/.+\s=\s.+\s(.+\s=\s.+)/\1/;` search and replace, keeping only the second part of the line

`push (@lines, $_);}` add the edited line to an array

`END` after all lines in the file have been processed, do the following

`if (@lines)` only do this if there were any modified lines in the file

`{print STDOUT "\n" . $ARGV . ":";` print a blank line, then the filename followed by a semicolon

`foreach (@lines){print "$_";}}}` print each line that was modifies in that file

`{} \;` this is a placeholder for the `find` result